# Cloudberry Backup Re-Uploading Copies Of Unchanged File

Tags: backup, cloudberry

We are using Cloudberry version 5.8.0.168 to backup from our server into Azure storage. The plan is using a daily block level backup, with a full weekly backup.

However, the full backup is currently re-uploading copies of every file in scope, despite the vast majority of them not having changed compared to the version already uploaded to Azure.

Is there an issue with version 5.8.0.168? Or is there something else I can try to prevent it making copies of unchanged files? This is currently blocking up our server as we have several backup plans all now running in parallel, as they are taking many days to complete.

Thanks very much for any help,

Martyn.

Comment: CloudBerry isn't discussed much here. Have you asked support? They're pretty good if you're a paying customer.

Comment: Thank you @Tim, I posted on here because it was one of the recommended channels on the Cloudberry Support page, but, if it's not discussed much on here, I'll contact their support directly. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked directly to Cloudberry support.

Comment: CloudBerrySupport answered the question and said "please contact us as we need to check your logs", but the answer was deleted as it didn't actually answer the question. You should contact them, then ask them to edit their question which provides an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this in the end by running the Consistency Check within Cloudberry against the Azure Storage Account.

This found a lot of warnings of files the Cloudberry database didn't know about, either locally or remote. It fixed all of these warnings and the backup began working normally again.